# "The Web is not marked as an application in IIS"

Tags: c#

I am using IIS 5.1 and .Net 2005. I'm getting an error while opening a .NET application as local ISS.

```
Error - The Web is not marked as an application in IIS.
```

I have checked the directory in IIS and it seems everything is in right place.

How might I resolve this?

Comment: Wow.  That's funny.  But seriously.  What is .NET 2005?  You mean 2.0, I guess?

Comment: Not surprising. The Web is a platform, not an application.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your virtual directory into an application:

http://www.tamilcodes.com/document.aspx?content=Tutorials&id=42

Comment: I have done all the steps which you have mentioned. I have convrted virtual directory into an application. But still the same error i am getting.